# Save a form input with the result of two others forms inputs of the same form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, forms, simple-form

I have a form(simple forms) with description, quantity and unitary cost.

I use JS to display every line subtotal and total, just for the user can see the total.

My problem is that I want to save the form total in an input that I have in the same form, maybe it isn't the best way to do it but I need to do it in that way.

The input "total" saves with the numer of the result of the other inputs (q1*v1)+(q2*v2), i don't need to display in real time just to save it when create the form

```html
<%= f.input :v1%> <!-- value of item 1 -->
<%= f.input :q1%> <!-- quantity of item 1 -->

<%= f.input :v2%> <!-- value of item 2 -->
<%= f.input :q2%> <!-- quantity of item 2 -->     

<%= f.input :total %> <!-- here i need to automaticle save the
 value of (v1*q1)+(v2*q2) when I hit the submit(create) button-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something you'd either do on the front-end with JavaScript or on the back-end with Rails

(I'm assuming you want to do this on the back-end since you're saying it only matters that it *saves* properly.)

For that, you'll want to put this logic into your ActiveRecord model in a `before_save` callback (logic, as a rule, shouldn't go into your Controller).

```rb
# app/controllers/my_models_controller.rb
class MyModelsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @model = MyModel.new(my_model_params)
    if @model.save
      # It worked
    else
      # It failed
    end
  end

  private

  def set_model
    #...
  end

  def my_model_params
    params.permit(:v1,v2,q1,q2)
  end
end

# app/models/my_model.rb
class MyModel
  attr_accessor :v1
  attr_accessor :v2
  attr_accessor :q1
  attr_accessor :q2

  before_save :calculate_total

  private

  def calculate_total
    @total = (v1*q1)+(v2*q2)
  end
end
```

This is just pseudo-code, but I hope it gives you a good idea of how to complete this. Test this out (it will need some adjustments) - that should work.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

@Patrick Thanks for give me the right approach, but I couldn't make it work, just save blank fields even the original q1 v1, in the end this code work for me

```html
before_save do
    self.total = (self.q1 * self.v1) * (self.q2 * self.v2)
  end
```